# Change div background and characteristics on link click using pseudo classes

Tags: html, css

Good day guys. I have a question about changing div elements when clicking on their links.

What I have is that there are 2 links named LINK 1 and LINK 2, arranged in horizontal order on the head of the code. Then there are 2 divs in the left, arranged vertically and are named DIV 1 and DIV 2. what it exactly does is that a specific div changes its background color when its corresponding link is clicked (LINK 1 to DIV 1, and vice versa). But I ran into a problem where I can't change the divs. Is there a way to correct it? Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
      <style>
                ul {list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: rgb(42,157,143);overflow: hidden;}
                li{float: left;} 
                li a:link{display: block; color: black; padding: 10px; text-decoration: none;}
                li a:visited{color: orange;}
                li a:hover {background-color: rgb(38,70,83); color: blue;}
                li a.active {background-color: rgb(138,177,125); color: red;}
                
                div.top:hover {center-align:0; margin:20px; width: 40%; border: solid; padding:0;}
                div.top: active {center-align:0; margin:20px; width: 40%; border: solid; padding:0; background-color: green;}
                #link1:active div.top {display: block;}
                div.bottom:hover {center-align:0; margin:20px; width: 40%; border: solid; padding:0;}
                div.bottom: active {center-align:0; margin:20px; width: 40%; padding:0; background-color: blue; border: 10px dotted green;}
                #link2:active div.bottom {display: block;}
                
      </style>
</head>
      <body>
            <nav>
                 <ul>
                     <li><a href="#link1" target="_blank">LINK 1</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#link2" target="_blank">LINK 2</a></li>
                  </ul>
             </nav>
             <div class="top"; style="center-align:0; margin:20px; width: 40%; border: solid; padding:0;">
             <h1 style="text-align:center;"> DIV 1 <h1>
             </div>
             <div class="bottom"; style="center-align:0; margin:20px; width: 40%; border: solid; padding:0;">
             <h1 style="text-align:center;"> DIV 2<p>
             </div>
             
       </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on links - link1 & link2. Is this something you trying to achive?

```js
alpha = (a) => {
  if(a === 'div1'){
  document.getElementById(a).style.background = "yellow";
  }
  else {
  document.getElementById(a).style.background = "green";
  }
}
```

```css
   div {height:100px; width:100px; border: 2px solid black;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a onclick="alpha('div1')" >LINK 1</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="alpha('div2')" >LINK 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div id="div1"></div>

<div id="div2"></div>
```